# LINQ distinct on 2 fields

Tags: linq

I have a LINQ query that returns data and I want to filter based on 2 fields (fkProfileID and fkOrgID) that are often the same.  I only want to show 1 record when fkProfileID and fkOrgID match, so it is similar to doing an SQL distinct, but on 2 fields rather than one.

My data will look like this (other fields have been removed) :

```
fkProfileID  fkOrgID
1            1001
1            1001
1            1001
2            1001
2            1001
1            1005
1            1005
```

So here I want to return only the following:

```
fkProfileID  fkOrgID
1            1001
2            1001
1            1005
```

Here is my current LINQ (both fields above are in tblUserRights), how do I need to change it to do this?

```
List<ProfileJSON> lstProfiles = (from r in _database.tblUserRights
                                         join p in _database.LuProfiles on r.fkProfileID equals p.luProfileID
                                         join o in _database.tblOrganisations on r.fkOrgID equals o.pkOrgID
                                         where r.fkUniqueID == intPKUserID
                                         orderby o.OrgDesc, p.ProfileName

                                         select new ProfileJSON
                                         {
                                             SiteID = o.pkOrgID,
                                             SiteName = o.OrgDesc,
                                             ProfileID = p.luProfileID,
                                             ProfileName = p.ProfileName
                                         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .Distinct() after your query

```
List<ProfileJSON> lstProfiles = (from r in _database.tblUserRights
                                     join p in _database.LuProfiles on r.fkProfileID equals p.luProfileID
                                     join o in _database.tblOrganisations on r.fkOrgID equals o.pkOrgID
                                     where r.fkUniqueID == intPKUserID
                                     orderby o.OrgDesc, p.ProfileName

                                     select new ProfileJSON
                                     {
                                         SiteID = o.pkOrgID,
                                         SiteName = o.OrgDesc,
                                         ProfileID = p.luProfileID,
                                         ProfileName = p.ProfileName
                                     }).Distinct().ToList(); //Distinct here
```